# How old did the man live to be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On a man's tombstone, it is said that one sixth of his life was spent in childhood and one twelfth as a teenager. One seventh of his life passed between the time he became an adult and the time he married; five years later, his son was born. Alas, the son died four years before he did. He lived to be twice as old as his son did.
Question- How old did the man live to be?

Comment: We know he made it passed his teenage years and that the spent $\frac{1}{12}$ his life as a teenager.  That's all you need to know.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485215/how-to-solve-the-problem-that-determines-the-age-of-diophantus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming the end of teen life as adulthood)

Let the man lived for $x$ years.

Childhood: $\frac{x}{6}$;
Teenager: $\frac{x}{12}$;
From the end of teenage/adulthood to married: $\frac{x}{7}$;
From marriage till his son was born: $5$;
Till his son was dead: $y$;
Till he died: $4$.

Summation of all these is equal to $x$. The second equation comes from the fact that the father lived to be twice as old as his son.

$$\frac{x}{6} + \frac{x}{12} + \frac{x}{7} + 5 + y + 4 = x$$
$$x = 2y$$
Substituting $y$ from the second equation in first,
$$\frac{x}{6} + \frac{x}{12} + \frac{x}{7} + 5 + \frac{x}{2} + 4 = x$$
$$\frac{3x}{4} + \frac{x}{7} + 9 = x$$
$$\frac{x}{4} - \frac{x}{7} = 9$$
$$x = 84, y = 42$$

Comment: Interestingly enough, his childhood lasted 14 years and his time as a teenager lasted 7 years, i.e. he was a teenager from age 14 to 21. Some people are late bloomers.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x}{6}+\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{7}+5+\frac{x}{2}+4=x\Rightarrow x=84$$The man lived for $84$ years.

Answer (score 1):

The question is invalid. Since there are 7 teenage years, he lived to 84. But also, since there are 13 childhood years, he lived to 78: a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe he's a late bloomer?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Warren Hill's comment:

There are $19-13+1=7$ teenage years, so letting $x$ be the person's age

$\frac{7}{x} = \frac{1}{12} \implies x = 84.$

The rest of the information is actually not needed in this problem.

Comment: Actually, this seems like a coincidence: The childhood is as twice as long as the teenagehood, which doesn't make sense if you fix the teenagehood at years 13 to 19.

Comment: Well, isn't that the definition of teenagehood?

Comment: It is. There is either an inconsistence or a translation error in this problem. I suspect the latter: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485215/how-to-solve-the-problem-that-determines-the-age-of-diophantus

Answer (score -1):

$84$ years

$\frac{x}{6}+\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{7} + 5 + y + 4 = 2y$. Simplifying this equation gives:
$\frac{11}{28} (x) + 9 = y$

Solve this for integer values of $x$ and $y$ using trial and error. Start with $x = 28$, $56$ and finally $84$ till you get an integer solution for $y$.

This gives $x = 84$ and $y = 42$

Comment: There is no need for trial and error as you can make use of the other equation $x=2y$. Substitute this in the equation that you got and see the magic unfold :D