# Diophantus' Lifespan

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle

Today I saw Diophantus' Epitaph. For those of you who don't know it and don't feel like googling:

> 'Here lies Diophantus,' the wonder behold. Through art algebraic, the
>   stone tells how old: 'God gave him his boyhood one-sixth of his life,
>   One twelfth more as youth while whiskers grew rife; And then yet
>   one-seventh ere marriage begun; In five years there came a bouncing
>   new son. Alas, the dear child of master and sage After attaining half
>   the measure of his father's life chill fate took him. After consoling
>   his fate by the science of numbers for four years, he ended his life.'
>
> Stated in prose, the poem says that Diophantus's youth lasts 1/6 of
>   his life. He grew a beard after 1/12 more of his life. After 1/7 more
>   of his life, Diophantus married. Five years later, he had a son. The
>   son lived exactly half as long as his father, and Diophantus died just
>   four years after his son's death.

From the [WolframAlpha blog](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantussRiddle.html). Now, when I see this, here's the equation I come up with, where x is Diophantus' lifespan:
$$\dfrac{x}{6} + \dfrac{x}{12} + \dfrac{x}{7} + 5 + \dfrac{x-4}{2} + 4 = x$$
The only part I'm not certain about is $\dfrac{x-4}{2}$. Basically, I reasoned that in order for his son to reach half his age, his age has to double. However, he lives 4 years after his age doubles, so we go with that to avoid doubling the 4 extra years. The problem is, solving this gets me $x=65.333..$. According to the WolframAlpha blog (and a [question on here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485215/how-to-solve-the-problem-that-determines-the-age-of-diophantus)), he was 84 when he died. However, here's the strange part. I haven't worked it out myself the way both WolframAlpha and the question did, but WolframAlpha's blog says

> "Solving this simultaneously gives S=42 as the age of the son and D=84 as the age of Diophantus."

Now, I don't claim to be great at math, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't work out. 2 * 42 is definitely 84, and the riddle states that Diophantus waits 4 years after reaching double his son's age to commit suicide. I know the people at WolframAlpha (and on here :)) are much smarter than me, so I assume I both set up my equation wrong and am somehow missing how their approach is solving the problem. Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: Aaaand got it (after reading the riddle like 80 times). Everyone else is interpreting the riddle just the way WolframAlpha says: "The son lived exactly half as long as his father." When I read "After attaining half the measure of his father's life chill fate took him," I thought it meant that the son died when he was half his father's age, not when he had reached half of his father's total lifespan. I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that WolframAlpha and I are equally right.

Comment: Well in that kind of language/culture they use "measure of life" to refer to the entire lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x}{6}+\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{7}+5+\frac{x}{2}+4=x.$$ 
So $\frac{3}{28}x=9$.

Comment: Yes, we interpreted the problem differently (see my comment on my question). This is an elegant way of solving the problem, but doesn't explain my "mistake."

Comment: "The son lived exactly half as long as his father" is I think unambiguous. Almost nothing is known about Diophantus' life, and there is scholarly dispute about the approximate period in which he lived. There is no reason to think that the problem has a historical basis.

Comment: That IS unambiguous. Unfortunately, that's a quote from Wolfram Alpha's simplification. The original riddle (which I was basing my calculations on) said "After attaining half the measure of his father's life chill fate took him." I interpreted this to mean "when he died, he was half as old as his father," not "he died when he was half the age his father would eventually reach before he died."

Comment: I have not yet located a Greek version, the translations wobble all over the place.

Comment: Two Latin sources say that Aeschylus died when an eagle dropped a tortoise on his bald head. http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plin.+Nat.+10.3&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0137